# Find $\alpha$ so that f is two times differentiable

Tags: functions, derivatives

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f : [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with:

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
x^\alpha \sin{\frac{1}{x}}, x \neq 0\\ 
0, x = 0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Find $\alpha$ so that $f$ is two times differentiable in point $0$.

The first condition I have is that $f$ must be continuous. I get $0^{\alpha - 1} = 0$, which is not useful. Next $f$ needs to be differentiable in $0$, but again I didn't get anything that could help.

Comment: Start by writing down the (formal) first and second derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $f'(0)$ is given by

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^\alpha\sin\frac{1}{x}-0}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}x^{\alpha-1}\sin\frac{1}{x}$$

if the limit exists and is finite. Since $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ oscillates wildly between $-1$ and $1$, we need $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{\alpha-1}=0$, i.e. we need $\alpha>1$.

Now for $x\neq 0$

$$f'(x)=\left(\alpha x \sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}\right)x^{\alpha-2}$$

and $f'(0)=0$, so $f''(0)$ is given by

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\alpha x \sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x}\right)x^{\alpha-3}$$

if the limit exists and is finite. The first term in the brackets goes to zero as $x\to 0$ while the second term oscillates wildly between $-1$ and $1$. Thus we need $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{\alpha-3}=0$, i.e. we need $\alpha>3$. We get  $f''(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The sinus part oscillates wildly between -1 and 1. So the $x^\alpha$ part should compensate for this. To make it once differentiable you
need that $(f(x)-f(0))/x=f(x)/x$ has a limit as $x\rightarrow 0$, which leads to $\alpha>1$ and then gives $f'(0)=0$. Now, the first derivative is
$$ f'(x) = \alpha x^{\alpha-1} \sin \frac{1}{x} - x^{\alpha-2} \cos \frac{1}{x}, \ \ x\neq 0$$
You need to play the same game and look for a condition for which $(f'(x)-f'(0))/x= f'(x)/x$ has a limit as $x\rightarrow 0$. Hint: This time it is the second term which behaves the worst, so what is the condition on $\alpha$?